# Text Area Height and width using zurb foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am quite new to zurb, infact just found it yesterday. I am liking it so far, but I can't seem to figure out something simple. I can do this using css but I wanted to know if there is another out-of-the-box approach to this.

I want to be able to set the width and height of a text area. The way it is on this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwZbh/

```
`<textarea id="content" placeholder="Nothing yet!!" class="large-12" style="margin: 0px -275.672px 0px 0px; height: 319px; width: 580px;"
```

Answer (score 11):

it's a small bug in foundation

open up your css, and add the following

```
textarea {
    height: auto;
}
```

then you will be able to style your textarea as you wish, and `rows` will work as well

example

```
<textarea rows="5" name="textareaname" cols="50"></textarea>
```

**UPDATE:**

This bug is now fixed in Foundation 5

Comment: As of now, the first part of this answer `height: auto` has been fixed in Foundation 5. We can now just add `rows="5"` and it works.

Comment: Did not know, did not have time to play with foundation 5, thanks for the heads up, i will update my answer